# Using spherical derivatives with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to plot the path of an object around a centre of mass.
Obviously this needs spherical coordinates.
The problem I encounter is with the derivatives.
The Derivatives in spherical coordinates are for

(radial, azimuthal, polar)  (r,theta,phi):

```
dr = r'
dϕ = r ϕ'
dθ = r Sin[ϕ] θ
```

Where the accelerations in theta and phi remain 0 for now.

But I need values for the initial velocity, this means that when I add the sinus to the NDSolve, it can't solve the set of equations;
This is the furthest I've come.
In truth, I'm not sure if this is the right approach or not, but solving the equations in Cartesian coordinates brings a lot more problems.

```
b = 20;
ball = First@NDSolve[{r''[t] == -9.81/r[t]^2, r[0] == 5, r'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[r[t] == 2.25, r'[t] -> -0.9 r'[t]], θ''[t] == 0,
  θ[0] == 0,r[0] θ'[0] == π/4, ϕ''[t] == 0,
  ϕ[0] == π,r[0] ϕ'[0] == π/4}, {r, θ, ϕ}, {t, 0, b}];
```

The following doesn't work (third row, added sinus):

```
ball = First @ NDSolve[{r''[t] == -9.81/r[t]^2, r[0] == 5, r'[0] == 0, 
 WhenEvent[r[t] == 2.25, r'[t] -> -0.9 r'[t]], θ''[t] == 0,
 θ[0] == 0,r[0] Sin[ϕ[0]] θ'[0] == π/4, ϕ''[t] == 0,
 ϕ[0] == π,r[0] ϕ'[0] == π/4}, {r, θ, ϕ}, {t, 0, b}];
```

I then plot with:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[{r[t] Sin[θ[t]] Cos[ϕ[t]] /. ball, 
      r[t] Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ϕ[t]] /. ball, 
      r[t] Cos[θ[t]] /. ball}, {t, 0, a}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed, Thick}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{r[t] Sin[θ[t]] Cos[ϕ[t]] /. ball, 
      r[t] Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ϕ[t]] /. ball, 
      r[t] Cos[θ[t]] /. ball}, {t, a - 0.001, a}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.05]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], 
    Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 2]]],
  {{a, b/100, "Time"}, b/100, b}]
```

Trying:

```
ball = First @ NDSolve[{x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + z''[t]^2 ==
 -9.81^2/(x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + z''[t]^2)^2, 
 x[0] == 3, y[0] == 3, z[0] == 3, x'[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
 z'[0] == 0, 
 WhenEvent[x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + z''[t]^2 == 2.25^2, 
  x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + z''[t]^2 -> -0.9 x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + 
  z''[t]^2]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, b}];
```

Returns an under-determined error.

I get that I have only one second derivative, but going all out (added row 3):

```
ball = First@NDSolve[{x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + 
 z''[t]^2 == -9.81^2/(x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + z''[t]^2)^2, 
 ArcTan[x[t], y[t]] == 0, ArcTan[z[t], Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2]] == 0,
 x[0] == 3, y[0] == 3, z[0] == 3, x'[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
 z'[0] == 0, 
 WhenEvent[x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + z''[t]^2 == 2.25^2, 
  x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + z''[t]^2 -> -0.9 x''[t]^2 + y''[t]^2 + 
  z''[t]^2]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, b}];
```

produces the messages:

> Warning: the rule (x'')[t]^2+(y'')[t]^2+(z'')[t]^2->-0.9 (x'')[t]^2+(y'')[t]^2+(z''[t]^2 will not directly set the state because the left-hand side is not a list of state variables. >>
>
> Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions. >>

Comment: Are you aware of the functions [`CoordinateTransformData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoordinateTransformData.html) and [`CoordinateChartData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoordinateChartData.html). They may help you formulated your problem in a way that allows _Mathematica_ to do more of the coordinate system transformation work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a systematic approach to this problem, starting from the Lagrangian: I denote the initial radial distance by `r0 = 5.` and use this value in writing the initial values for the other variables. The time of the simulation is `tmax = 30`.

Everything starts by defining the radius vector `rVec` in terms of spherical coordinates. Inserting this into the kinetic energy and subtracting the potential energy, we get the Lagrangian. The equations of motion `eqs` are automatically generated by using the function  [`EulerEquations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerEquations.html) from the `VariationalMethods` package which I load at the beginning. That way, we can be sure that the translation to spherical coordinates is done correctly.

```
<< VariationalMethods`

rVec[t_] := 
 r[t] {Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[θ[t]], 
   Sin[ϕ[t]] Sin[θ[t]], Cos[θ[t]]}

lagrangian = 1/2 Simplify[rVec'[t].rVec'[t]] + 9.81/r[t]

(*
==> 9.81/r[t] + 
 1/2 (Derivative[1][r][t]^2 + 
    r[t]^2 (Derivative[1][θ][t]^2 + 
       Sin[θ[t]]^2 Derivative[1][ϕ][t]^2))
*)

eqs = 
 EulerEquations[lagrangian, {r[t], θ[t], ϕ[t]}, t]

(*
==> {-(9.81/r[t]^2) + 
   r[t] (Derivative[1][θ][t]^2 + 
      Sin[θ[t]]^2 Derivative[1][ϕ][t]^2) - (
    r^′′)[t] == 0, 
 r[t] (-2 Derivative[1][r][t] Derivative[1][θ][t] + 
     r[t] (Cos[θ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] Derivative[1][ϕ][
          t]^2 - (θ^′′)[t])) == 
  0, -r[t] Sin[θ[
     t]] (2 Sin[θ[t]] Derivative[1][r][t] Derivative[
       1][ϕ][t] + 
     r[t] (2 Cos[θ[t]] Derivative[1][θ][t] Derivative[
          1][ϕ][t] + 
        Sin[θ[t]] (ϕ^′′)[t])) == 0}
*)

r0 = 5.;
tmax = 30;

sol = 
  First@NDSolve[
    Join[eqs, {r[0] == r0, 
      r'[0] == 0, θ[0] == 0.01, θ'[0] == Pi/4/r0, ϕ[0] == Pi, 
        ϕ'[0] == Pi/4/r0, 
      WhenEvent[r[t] == 2.25, r'[t] -> -0.9 r'[t]]}], {r[t], θ[
      t], ϕ[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}];

Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 2.25]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[rVec[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 100]]
```

[image: bounces]

In this plot, I had to increase the number of plot points to show the details of the bounces correctly. The motion is completely confined to a two-dimensional plane due to the conservation of angular momentum. The sphere is made slightly opaque to show the orbit better when you rotate the graphic.

I also had to change the starting condition for the polar angle away from $\theta=0$ because the spherical coordinate system is singular at the pole. So I chose `θ[0] == 0.01` above.

Comment: I feel kind of silly not to try a Lagrangian.
Informative explanation, thanks.